# How to show zooming scalling values shows in camerapage android xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, zooming

Currently i am implementing zoomin and zoomout in camerapagerenderer but while zoomin and zoomout scalling values not shown in UI view, how to achieve this in android for above screenshot try to achive like these[image]

```
    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
            {
    
                switch (e.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask)
                {
                    case MotionEventActions.Down:
                        oldDist = getFingerSpacing(e);
                        break;
                    case MotionEventActions.Move:
                        float newDist = getFingerSpacing(e);
                        if (newDist > oldDist)
                        {
                            //mCamera is your Camera which used to take picture, it should already exit in your custom Camera
                            handleZoom(true, camera);
                        }
                        else if (newDist < oldDist)
                        {
                            handleZoom(false, camera);
                        }
                        oldDist = newDist;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

 private void handleZoom(bool isZoomIn, global::Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
        {
                global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
                if (parameters.IsZoomSupported)
                {
                    int maxZoom = parameters.MaxZoom;
                    int zoom = parameters.Zoom;

                    if (isZoomIn && zoom < maxZoom)
                    {
                        zoom++;

                    }
                    else if (zoom > 0)
                    {
                        zoom--;
                    }
                    parameters.Zoom = zoom;
    camera.SetPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
                        PrepareAndStartCamera();
    
}
```

Comment: Anyone pls tell me about these issue how to resolve

Comment: It seems that you've solved the problem, let's focus on that thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916910/zoomin-percentage-values-shows-in-cameralayout-in-android-xamarin-forms.